# Dealing with big data to perform random forest classification

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, bigdata

I am currently working on my thesis, which involves dealing with quite a sizable dataset: ~4mln observations and ~260ths features. It is a dataset of chess games, where most of the features are player dummies (130k for each colour).

As for the hardware and the software, I have around 12GB of RAM on this computer. I am doing all my work in Python 3.5 and use mainly pandas and scikit-learn packages.

My problem is that obviously I can't load this amount of data to my RAM. What I would love to do is to generate the dummy variables, then slice the database into like a thousand or so chunks, apply the Random Forest and aggregate the results again.

However, to do that I would need to be able to first create the dummy variables, which I am not able to do due to memory error, even if I use sparse matrices. Theoretically, I could just slice up the database first, then create the dummy variables. However, the effect of that will be that I will have different features for different slices, so I'm not sure how to aggregate such results.

**My questions:**
1. How would you guys approach this problem? Is there a way to "merge" the results of my estimation despite having different features in different "chunks" of data?
2. Perhaps it is possible to avoid this problem altogether by renting a server. Are there any trial versions of such services? I'm not sure exactly how much CPU/RAM would I need to complete this task.

Thanks for your help, any kind of tips will be appreciated :)

Comment: For the second question: Maybe be the AWS student program would be interesting for you: https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you give CloudxLab a try.

Though it is not free it is quite affordable ($25 for a month). It provides complete environment to experiment with various tools such as HDFS, Map-Reduce, Hive, Pig, Kafka, Spark, Scala, Sqoop, Oozie, Mahout, MLLib, Zookeeper, R, Scala etc. Many of the popular trainers are using CloudxLab.